# Invalid use of incomplete type (for a pointer to atomic integer variable)

Tags: c++, pointers, incomplete-type, stdatomic

When I write this,

```
std::atomic<int> * tmp = new std::atomic<int>();
```

g++ compiler returns an error saying

> ```
> invalid use of incomplete type "struct std::atomic<int>"
> ```

Why is it giving this error? How can I evade this? Do I need to wrap the atomic variable inside a class and use its pointer instead?

Same thing happens with smart pointers too.

```
std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<int>> tmp = std::make_shared<std::atomic<int>> ();
```

Comment: You need `#include <atomic>`

Comment: ... and `#include<memory>` for `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I had included memory already but atomic was absent. Trying now.

Comment: Error is gone now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*incomplete type* is the big clue here given by your compiler: compiler diagnostics are extremely good these days - well worth reading!

It means you haven't `#include`d the correct files - since the type is not *complete* at the point of compilation.

*Always* include C++ standard library files explicitly. In this case you need `<atomic>` and `<memory>`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to

```
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
```

To get access to the atomics you are using and the shared_ptr.